# Removing a div row using button click

Tags: jquery

I have div row with some controls on it. I have add and remove button. The Add button click removes the particular row. When I try to remove the particular row only the top row gets removed , not the others.

Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4dy6g8bu/1/

```js
var $addButton = $(".btn.add");
$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
    $cloned.clone(true, true).insertAfter($cloner);
});
var $cloned = $('.clone').clone(true, true);

var $removeButton = $(".btn.remove");

 $removeButton.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");
            $cloner.remove();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone-container">
    <div class="clone">
        <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
        <select id="select1" name="select1" class="">
            <option>Select One:</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <span class="controls">
            <a href="#" class="btn add">+</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn remove">−</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Questions are.

1. How to remove the respective row on each button click.
2. Need to restrict the remove button if there is only one row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your button generated dynamic, you need change click event to

```
$('body').on("click", '.btn.remove', function (e) {
```

Prevent remove first button

```
if($(".btn.remove").length == 1){ return; }
```

```js
var $addButton = $(".btn.add");
$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
    $cloned.clone(true, true).insertAfter($cloner);
});
var $cloned = $('.clone').clone(true, true);

var $removeButton = $(".btn.remove");

 $('body').on("click", '.btn.remove', function (e) {
            if($(".btn.remove").length == 1){
               return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");
            //console.log("a" + $cloner);
            $cloner.remove();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone-container">
    <div class="clone">
        <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
        <select id="select1" name="select1" class="">
            <option>Select One:</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <span class="controls">
            <a href="#" class="btn add">+</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn remove">−</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks . This works. How to prevent the last(one row should be there) row to deleted

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It work for me.

Html

```
<div id="clone-container">
<div class="clone">
    <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
    <select id="select1" name="select1" class="">
        <option>Select One:</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <span class="controls">
        <a href="#" class="btn add">+</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn remove">−</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Js

```
var $addButton = $(".btn.add");
$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
   $cloned.clone(true, true).insertAfter($cloner);
 });
 var $cloned = $('.clone').clone(true, true);

 var $removeButton = $(".btn.remove");

 $("#clone-container").on('click', '.btn.remove',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");

        var count = $("#clone-container .clone").length;
        if(count > 1)
        {
           $cloner.remove();
        }


     } )
```